# HELP: application defined or object defined error when saving a workbook

Tags: vba

I get the application defined or object defined error when I save an excel file. I get an error at line: "wbk.SaveAs FPath"

Here is my code:

```
Dim wbk As Workbook, FPath As String

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("\\network\drive\Template.xlsm", False, ReadOnly:=True,       IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)

FPath = "\\network\drive\Saved_Files\" & _
"File Number - " & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & ".xlsm"

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
.Range("A2").Value = Test....
End With

***wbk.SaveAs FPath***

wbk.Close True
Set wbk = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you checked that the workbook is being successfully opened and that wbk is not nothing?  Also have you checked that FPath is a valid path?

Comment: Can you put a break on the line and edit your question with the contents of the FPath variable?  Also, are you sure the user running this has rights to create files in that path?

Comment: Does cell A1 contain any special characters that are not allowed in save names?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem the other day too, You can not save to a network drive like that. It has to be mapped as a drive letter for it to work.

At least I couldn't find a way around it while tinkering with it. Excel does not seem to like network drives as a path name.

**EDITED** : Tim is right, my problem I stated above is a problem that just requires a hot fix from Microsoft. Shouldn't be on all machines.

Maybe this link could help though, they are describing the same type of issue. See the first comment, a lot of people seemed to have success with the code inside.

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/06/21/unc-path/

Comment: That's not the case (unless you have some strange settings...) I'm using UNC paths all the time, with no issue.

Comment: Most likely a permissions issue.